# Android OpenGL ES 2.0, Compute Normal for each triangle

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need to compute Normals for each Triangle Face (not for each vertex) using Opengl ES 2.0 in Android. But I can't pass attribute in the **Fragment Shader** directly.

Found one solution: Repeat vertices for each *Triangle*, and pass Triangle face Normal as an Attribute in **Vertex Shader**.

But I don't want to duplicate the vertices. I am drawing triangle using *Vertex Indices*.

So, *a vertex is shared by more than one triangle*, then how should I compute Triangle face Normals.

p.s. I am a newbie in opengl.

Comment: You already explained it to yourself. You can only share vertices, if those vertices are the same. So if 2 vertices have the same position, but different normals, then they can't represent the same vertex. You could use a geometry shader, but it's way more practical to just not share vertices like that.

Comment: Geometry shader is not available in Opengl ES 2.0..
I need to color Triangles according to their orientations (that's why I need surface Normal, and can't duplicate vertices as well), as in this image.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jam3/jam3-lesson-webgl-shader-threejs/master/images/3.png

Comment: Didn't notice it was OpenGL ES. That however doesn't change what I originally said. Don't share vertices that clearly can't be shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is just to duplicate vertices. The vertex shader is very rarely a bottleneck. I do not know your specific needs, however, there are cirumstances when duplicating a vertex is not a good solution. For example, if the mesh is skinned and animated that means a lot of computation happens in the vertex shader. Another case is when the mesh is animated in some weird way in the vertex shader and you have to recompute the normals. Clearly, you cannot compute per face normals in the vertex shader. You could do that in the geometry shader, but we do not have one in OpenGL ES 2.0. However, there is a simple solution - compute normals in fragment shader! So, if duplication of vertices does not work for you, here is the solution:

1. We will need an OpenGL extension - standard_derivatives, which is widely supported, but you will still need to check if it is supported on the device before running the code. To enable the extension, you will have to add the following line to the fragment shader before it's code:

   ```
   #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
   ```
2. We will need a varying variable for the vertex position in the world coordinates. It should be computed in the vertex shader and how it is done depends much on your shader. It is used for many needs, so you may already compute it in your vertex shader. So let's assume, that we have this line in the fragment shader:

   ```
   varying vec3 positionWorld;
   ```
3. We will need a view matrix of the camera. It is possible that you are already passing one to the fragment shader. Let's assume that we have this uniform in the fragment shader:

   ```
   uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
   ```
4. Now, we are going to compute the normal. First, we compute a normal in view space and then transform into the worldspace. To compute normal in the viewspace, we use derivative functions:

   ```
   vec3 normalViewSpace = normalize(cross(dFdx(positionWorldSpace), dFdy(positionWorldSpace)));
   ```

   Here a derivative of position is taken with respect to x and y coordinate in screen space. That means that we have two vectors that are in lay in the surface plane. To get normal to the surface we do a cross product. Sure, the result is not a unit vector, so we need also to normalize it.
5. The last step is to compute normal in the worldspace. View matrix applies a transformation from world space to view space. One could think that we need to compute the inverse of it since we need to go from view space to world space, but because view matrix is orthonormal, the transpose of that matrix is also its inverse, so the code will be:

   ```
   vec3 normalWorldSpace = (vec4(normalViewSpace, 0.0) * viewMatrix).xyz;
   ```
6. To make life easier, we can wrap everything into a function:

   ```
   vec3 ReconstructNormal(vec3 positionWorldSpace) 
   {
       vec3 normalViewSpace = normalize(cross(dFdx(positionWorldSpace), dFdy(positionWorldSpace)));
       vec3 normalWorldSpace = (vec4(normalViewSpace, 0.0) * viewMatrix).xyz;
       return normalWorldSpace;
   }
   ```

Now we have a reconstructed normal in world space. Below, just a simple example, why this can be very useful. Note, that since it uses WebGL, it is also pretty much OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible.

```js
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh;
var uniforms;

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

init();
animate();

function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
    camera.position.z = 0.6;
    camera.position.y = 0.2;
    camera.rotation.x = -0.45;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var boxGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.75, 0.75, 32, 32);
     
    var heightMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAFiUAABYlAUlSJPAAAAeeSURBVFhHTdfFq1VfFAfwfbzP7q5ndwcm2IqKgQoiOhQFQXAgDpxecObAP0ARdGJMdGDhwAILO7C7uzvv73wWHPltuLx7z9l7rfWNtc552ZQpUypt27ZN7dq1S/9f7969S1evXk116tRJtWrVSj9//kzfv39PX79+jfvdu3dPpVIp3b9/P3Xo0CH1798/tWrVKjVs2DBt3749vX//PnXr1i3VqFEj9jVq1Ci9efMm3blzJ7Vp0yY1adIk/fr1K2Xz5s2r2CjRy5cv42/r1q3Tnz9/0smTJ6MQh+vVq5du3LgRwSSsrq5OnTp1Sq9fv05fvnyJ38OHD0+7du1K+/bti8Jq166dfvz4EQU7v2TJkoh35cqVADN37txU1bJly0hm+VskaNasWXr+/HkEUe2AAQNSnz590ufPn1OLFi3Sx48f0+3btyO5fUePHo2CJ0yYkJo2bRpgqqqqIq4lzsaNG/8xaCkqGJDYjbdv36aaNWtGkKlTpwadEBTyPHz4MB0/fjw9efIknTp1Kn5bM2fODMqdlUjiFy9epAYNGsR9zCnYck0u+6KA5cuXVz59+hQXX716FbTWrVs3jR8/PnTt169f2rJlS9q2bVsEcNCi56NHj2IvyTAE+ePHj8Mv1u/fv0PSW7duhYwF01h2RsHZ4sWLw4SoVZ1No0ePjorpK8izZ8/+oejRo0dq37590P306dPYL6nCly5dGqyRD5uNGzf+J5Gk58+fj+Lu3bsXHsBsKa+6rHLJaevQgQMHIgGKbt68GYV8+/YtdBVM5c2bN093794NFnSE89euXYvvf//+Tbxlr2u6yHfxFaczLl26FEbNunTpUhk8eHAaMmRIOJSW6NUZUEvKB5IVa+DAgWncuHERvH79+oHGXmcZFgs+FpYktQ8b2OzVq1dI53wp17n84cOH0B/1c+bMiWIk6dixYxSjvzEjETTMh2IsYO/BgweRHAuoJomCJVq0aFHq2bNn9P/FixdDUrIxKtlKq1atKgtq8+HDhyOhBJs3b46gDEozruYBByWlJbSuW8ypKEEZbMyYMWnatGnxe/bs2SGj8zoIEKDFz9atW1dRoemltVRIQ0msQYMGxV9ONrlobpLpDguNCu7du3cwggVzBOUkVfzIkSMDGIDXr1+PYu0HvJQjL2sRSFUkuRvah0sVhTKGLFAzUWEwaEzBYujwjFiuQ01rPoAYesAUpJMUm61evboisCQuQLhnz55/wwJtClQxYxWTU3KLsxXgnsS6BpBiovouJqOPGjUq/GI/QwIYg0ilKmLCNWvWRKUYUIDrqtdeJqT29JAih6SYcV4y5yR2DgAsYKpz586xjyx8Ip4zfme5xhUobUIvhJI5LKilUnMAU5s2bUpHjhyJBJZkffv2TQsXLgxvSEhv0ulzC1rJ0C85mbW2XKU8cZluWocEivAdza6jmpkEKbrCb0uRCrAUp6hZs2bF044xtZ72dj3LstjP5L67RopS/oQr63HjGE2VSiUOqVYxKNVqdPRhKMbq2rVrJMUMUyoacmZ0HxMSug89YyteLuPcHvKGCaGlH00dKGZ10QkGEjQWlhiPhgzlGWLSKdp+Le2ae5gS234GFBsDpijmgCvllZXR5YJhxFyQCwYxrQREm6ECAZbco+HYsWNjJqDTnt27d8fEwwBAihfPuwPGMIExw4qpS/mXsocLFFpNVaq0UQIHtRYkPsxqL4Pmz5H4LjnjOnfs2LF/b0H+8g0wigGAAXnkwoULYdRSfrhMe4FpjWp6QsOx0Jpwng/QFAUKcOLEifjus3///kCGZtT7bi/UZCMxf/Ca/TqPjNnEiRMrKGIgzvRxoxjFWgxaBaLNfc91j9PipbUwnTZkLOMWYtrzku/YIqX9ZoHCmDJbuXJlxWFoVeqANXny5PiLdgEFGDFiRDp06FCg8c5g2Y9qUhTUkwPdEENrDRs2LJ4FJOEznUHebO3atRUDA21QM6MAPgynALoxFy/Q2D7f7ZWUhBZ2UKx4OpMBelLw06RJkyIPBrFw+vTpVMo1LqPDDQm9C+YvqoFSO27dujXt3bs3ng9aS1D7+EJxinAeEwrTFZ4dUGJAUQrUzszOI86KxV/ZggULKtB6WHC+YKqmt5dRSM+cORMIeUVy+/Uyr/CBYJiQLP9HJ15gCo8oBAOSkxEoIMQyM7INGzbEW7HFB2YCGplFN+hpKMkgqUDYcoa+06dPD13piQGv85KuX78+nhnFdFSgj9gex2YAk2b5W0s8jpkINTZLzNG+Q2mj32iGwBBCP5mgNVpNOoigO3fuXPQ4FgojAiGOLlHk0KFD4z0y/jFxiCksdKFZzxfz3JLQHkm9sDKVB5QgHL1ixYo4y9DenhQAGFnd12FAzJ8/P+IfPHgwnT17NpXyqstQ0Jx5zHSoTTeUFg8nlF++fDkQGiJ0J5l79kLpRVZg5739OiOGxM6ZJ87633HHjh0x9Er5y2PZTYZBPRSqdojZvFCqmAcgkojmPgaL/xfpumzZsvjN8SYqnwCEQei1pt9A7Ny5M4CZrlV0Qa8ukNwmfz1gFKFKukPqugQSksB0dI3RdMuMGTNCazJoNxK6rztIx/liGWgYr66uTv8BU33Si9zKcpYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
         
    heightMap.wrapT = heightMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

    uniforms = {u_time: {type: "f", value: 0.0 }, u_heightMap: {type: "t",value:heightMap} };

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide, 
        wireframe: false,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment_shader').textContent
    });


    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
    mesh.rotation.x = 3.14 / 2.0;
    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1 );
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    onWindowResize();

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize(event) {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render() {
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    uniforms.u_time.value += delta;
    //mesh.rotation.z += delta * 0.5;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
    body { margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>

<script id="fragment_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
    
    varying vec3 positionWorld; // position of vertex in world coordinates
    
    vec3 ReconstructNormal(vec3 positionWorldSpace) 
    {
        vec3 normalViewSpace = normalize(cross(dFdx(positionWorldSpace), dFdy(positionWorldSpace)));
        vec3 normalWorldSpace = (vec4(normalViewSpace, 0.0) * viewMatrix).xyz;
        return normalWorldSpace;
    }

    // Just some example of using a normal. Here we do a really simple shading
    void main( void ) 
    {
        vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
        vec3 normal = ReconstructNormal(positionWorld);
        float diffuse = max(dot(lightDir, normal), 0.0);
        vec3 albedo = vec3(0.2, 0.4, 0.7);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(albedo * diffuse, 1.0);    
    }
</script>

<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    uniform lowp sampler2D u_heightMap;
    uniform float u_time;
    
    varying vec3 positionWorld;
                
    // Example of vertex shader that moves vertices
    void main()
    {
        vec3 pos = position;
        vec2 offset1 = vec2(1.0, 0.5) * u_time * 0.01;
        vec2 offset2 = vec2(0.5, 1.0) * u_time * 0.01;
        float hight1 = texture2D(u_heightMap, uv + offset1).r * 0.02;
        float hight2 = texture2D(u_heightMap, uv + offset2).r * 0.02;
        pos.z += hight1 + hight2; 
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( pos, 1.0 );
        positionWorld = mvPosition.xyz;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: "Compute normals in fragment shader" is the one that I wanted. I wanted to render triangles and rotate on touch events, and they should change colors according to their computed normals.